An advanced formula for getting serial nos automatically in excel
Can you help me write a formula starting from A4 cell to A20 cell for the serial no of the students to get a result like the serials in this photo.
conditions:

First non empty row will get the serial 1 and then increasing by 1
After that it will check the columns B and D. Identical columns get same serial no. for that rows.
For an empty row serial no will skip to the next row. Please check the photo and help me.

=IF(AND(B5<>"", D5<>""), IF(COUNTIFS(B$4:B5, B5, D$4:D5, D5) > 1, MATCH(B5&D5, B$4:B5&D$4:D5, 0), ROW()-4), "")

It is not working if first row is empty.


Are rows in B5:B20 always completely empty?

This solution does not use LET, so will work in older versions of Excel.  However, in some of them you may need to enter it as an Array Formula (i.e. with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
=IF(COUNTA($B4:$E4)>0, IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A3, MATCH(1, --($B$3:$B3=$B4)*--($D$3:$D3=$D4), 0)), IFERROR(MAX($A$3:$A3), 0)+1), "")

Breaking it down:
IF(COUNTA($B4:$E4)>0, […], "")

This will skip empty rows.  Otherwise, it will look for a Serial Number.
IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A3, MATCH(1, --($B$3:$B3=$B4)*--($D$3:$D3=$D4), 0)), […])

This will check Columns B and D, from row 3 until the previous row, and check if any of those rows contain the same Name and DoB as the current row.  If so, it will return the Serial Number from that row.  If not…
IFERROR(MAX($A$3:$A3), 0)+1

It will find the largest Serial Number that has already been allocated, and add 1 to that.

It is working now. I have a questions. will it work if i have more data i.e more rows and columns?

@KurumbaDasparaFPSchool It will work for any number of rows — however, if you want the condition to include more columns, then you will need to update the COUNTA range and the MATCH condition (i.e. if you also wanted to match on Column C, then you would need MATCH(1, --($B$3:$B3=$B4)*--($C$3:$C3=$C4)*--($D$3:$D3=$D4), 0))

Here's one way (probably overkill), and you require Excel 365:
=LET(_Data,$B$4:$E$19,
_Name,CHOOSECOLS(_Data,1),
_Birth,CHOOSECOLS(_Data,3),
_UniNZ,UNIQUE(FILTER(_Data,TAKE(_Data,,1)<>"","")),
_Rank,XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,1)&CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,3),
     CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,1)&CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,3))
_Apply,XLOOKUP(_Name&_Birth,CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,1)&CHOOSECOLS(_UniNZ,3),
     _Rank,""),
_Apply)

Formula applied in cell A5 of your sheet:


Is it not possible to do this by a formula in Excel 2021? Also include the 3rd column(Write the formula starting from A4 cell). Because 3rd column may not be empty in the future.

@KurumbaDasparaFPSchool see update, LET works in Excel 2021 as well; give it a go I'd say.

I have copy pasted the formula in A5 cell in excel 2021. it is giving #NAME error. Also include the 3rd column(Write the formula starting from A4 cell). Because 3rd column may not be empty in the future.

@KurumbaDasparaFPSchool I've edited, missed a few translation errors. TAKE and CHOOSECOLS might translate into something else if your Excel isn't in English either.
